# Why expo-cli must be installed globally?

Tags: global, expo

The official way of working with `expo-cli` is to install it globally, see https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/#installing-expo-cli:

> Installing Expo CLI
>
> ```
> # Install command line tools
> npm install --global expo-cli
> ```

However, I never found any explanation about why it is supposed to be global (other than that this simplifies the initial `expo init` command). To my thinking, having a global package undermines the whole idea behind npm and local node_modules. Essentially, `expo-cli` is a direct dependency of the project. It's used for running the dev version with `expo start` and also for creating production builds.

Different versions of `expo-cli` will work differently, they may even expect different values in `app.config.ts`. That means it's not safe to upgrade `expo-cli` globally for one project and then return working with an older project which has been created and maintained with an older version of (global) `expo-cli`.

None of this would have happened if `expo-cli` were a normal local project dependency like `expo` (the SDK package).

So, my question is: **is there a real reason for keeping `expo-cli` global**? What do I lose if I move it to local project dependencies? How come Expo documentation never even mentions such option?

Comment: I'm curious what the answer is on this if you find it. I can't get the latest version of expo-cli to work if installed locally to my package, it can only work globally. I was able to use it locally previously.

Comment: I've simply installed it as a devDepedency and everything works fine so far.